# Slow Internet Mac Yosemite Recovery Doom (MacBook Air, Early 2015)

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, disk-utility, recovery

Product: MacBook Air(early 2015) with OS X Yosemite.

The issue is, that I happen to have my Yosemite reinstalled, so I restarted my MacBook and at the sound of the chime(startup sound of Yosemite), I pressed <kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and subsequently selected the Disk Utility. 
Once into that, I erased my whole Macintosh HD and then restarted the computer
after which I was expecting the reinstall to be done automatically.

I am a novice in the Mac world.

Now once after the reinstall, I was forced into a screen with 4 options of reinstalling, Disk Utility, Time Machine and help from Apple.

I tried to reinstall, but due to a slow internet connection, I wasn't able to reinstall using Internet Recovery.

Now I created a bootable disk with "InstallESD.dmg" (using tansmac on windows)
This copy of installed is the one downloaded from macworld torrents.
It was after that I restarted the computer this time pressing only the <kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd> key and then all I had was this black screen with a box that asked me for the network I had.

I selected mine in a hope it might work with my USB but it just shows an Internet Recovery option with a globe which I cannot afford due to my slow internet connection. Is there any specific key to select the bootable image because it isn't appearing there?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is a problem with the USB installer. To confirm this, restart holding Option + R to return to Disk Utility, and verify you formatted the drive as "Mac OS X Extended (Journaled).

If you have a working bootable usb, holding the "option" key should show you the Startup Manager menu:

[image]

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204417

Here are a few tutorials on creating Bootable USB OS X installers:

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-mac-os-x-yosemite-bootable-usb-using-diskmaker-x/

[How do I create a Mac bootable USB drive using Windows?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142169/how-do-i-create-a-mac-bootable-usb-drive-using-windows)

http://www.makarandmane.com/computer/tips-and-tricks/apple-mac-os-x/create-bootable-usb-mac-os-x-installer-from-windows/