# Install OS X on a MacBook Pro with empty SSD

Tags: macos

I have a MacBook Pro Retina 13.3" which had OS X 10.10. I erased the entire SSD with Disk Manager and tried to reinstall OS X. Unfortunately, my internet connection isn't good so it would take more than two days to download the installation files, so I downloaded the OS X .dmg on another computer and I made an USB bootable device with OS X 10.10 using PowerISO on Windows 7. Now when I try to install it using the C or CMD+R key, it doesn't show up. I only have the option to use Internet Recovery and I can't use it because it doesn't load. After a while it says "apple.com/support -2002F".

Any help, guys? And sorry for my bad english, haha.

Thank you.

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142169/how-do-i-create-a-mac-bootable-usb-drive-using-windows

Comment: Hold option key during boot

Answer (score 1):

⌘R only opens a specific preexisting partition on a hard drive that's already had OS X installed, so it makes sense that it wouldn't get you anywhere. You want to hold down Option as you press the Power button and watch the computer boot up. That tells the computer to list all the drives you can possibly boot from, and then you just select your bootable drive using the arrow keys and Return.

Comment: I'm the thread creator. I've lost my email. Unfortunately the only option I see on the screen is Internet Recovery :(

Comment: @Ignacio Then maybe something's wrong with your USB drive. Do you have another Mac, or a friend with a Mac, so you can make a bootable drive [the Apple-sanctioned way](http://www.macworld.com/article/2367748/how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-10-10-yosemite-install-drive.html)?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I only have a Windows 7 PC here. And my dead Mac.

Comment: I have heard that if you have access to an Apple store, they will let you use their WiFi to reinstall the OS. Failing that, do you like Starbucks coffee?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold option Key during booting process, then click on 'install OSX', it will bring you to the installation process with disk utility where you can create a partition for your new OS, make sure to just wipe it in correct format which usually would be OSX Journaled, it can also be APFS if you're using SSD and installing anything from 10.13 upwards.