# How to restore OS X after installing Windows in a single boot configuration

Tags: macos, imac, windows, install

I want to restore OS X after installing Windows in a single boot configuration.
So Windows is occupying the whole disk. Now I want to erase the hard disk and restore Mac OS X Mavericks. How do I do this?

Comment: We need more information; what Mac do you have (i.e MacBook Pro Retina Late 2013).  Also, what resources you have access to, like another Mac, a Windows PC, etc.  In order to give you instructions we need to know where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be easy. Follow these steps:

1. Create a bootable drive using a USB for OS X Mavericks.
2. Plug in your bootable USB drive and Restart your Mac while holding the Option key.
3. When it restarts, you'll have a few options.
4. Select the Disk Utility option.
5. In the window, at the top of the left bar, select your Mac's Main Drive and proceed with the installation.

This procedure automatically erase the content of your HD and so remove the Windows installed.

---

**EDIT**: In [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) you can find information to create a bootable drive USB for instal OS X Mavericks. Moreover, if you don't have access to a Mac computer you can follow [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142169/how-do-i-create-a-mac-bootable-usb-drive-using-windows) to proceed with a Windows computer.

Comment: I do not know how to create  a bootable drive using a USB for OS X Mavericks. I hope that separates more . Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @osama I update the answer.

Comment: thank you so much for cooperating, But I can not log in to the Mac or took a copy of it.

Comment: @osama -  We still need to know what Mac it is - edit it into your original question. Not all Macs can boot from USB.

Comment: thanks , but I want to burn mac os x el captain in flash  memory from windows And install it in the same computer ( I mac )

Answer (score 1):

You can restore OS X in Internet Recovery Mode if you have a newer Mac:

- Boot to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. The prerequisites for an Internet Recovery are listed here: [Recovery/Internet Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718).
  In a few words you need the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated for a successful internet recovery.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot to the Recovery Netboot image which is loaded from an Apple/Akamai server.
- Open *Disk Utility* and partition your internal disk: GUID partition scheme (use the "Options..." button at the bottom of the main pane for this), one partition, journaled HFS+.

  Sometimes *Disk Utility* won't allow you to erase the internal disk: open *Terminal* and enter `diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0` and `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk0 bs=512 count=1`. Then retry to erase the disk with *Disk Utility*.
- Close *Disk Utility*
- Open *Restore OS X* and restore the original OS X. This will restore the OS X version your Mac came with.
- After rebooting and configuring your Mac open *App Store*, download and install Mac OS X Mavericks (if an older OS X version was installed previously).

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck in Disk Utility not formatting your drive. Go back to Windows OS installation USB and format/delete all partition (during the process of installing Windows) after you only have one unpartitioned drive showing, quit the Windows install and restart the machine. Start the Internet recovery now by following http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718 pressing Shift-Option-Command-R while you start. After opening the Disk Utility this time you should only see the Mac drive. Erase and the reinstall your Mac OS.

The key here is that Windows drive had to be unpartitioned by Windows installation process. This worked for me.