# How to get DMG file for making macOS USB on Windows PC?

Tags: windows, usb, startup

I saw [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142169/how-do-i-create-a-mac-bootable-usb-drive-using-windows) discussion and updates on StackExchange on making macOS USB on Windows. I'm unable to comment there, so I'm posting a new question. I have been trying everything from that page, but as of now the method with TransMac is the only one working, because I have the DMG file for High Sierra.

Now that the High Sierra is old, I want to know whether there is any way make or download bootable DMG file for newer versions like Mojave or macOS Catalina? I did a Google search and found a [solution](https://www.winytips.com/convert-macos-app-to-bootable-dmg-iso/), on Google, but the result is not positive. Is there a reliable alternative?

Comment: You can either use Internet Recovery from the Mac in question, or Install High Sierra then update it, once you're signed into iCloud. You can **make** the USB key on Windows but you cannot **access** any other macOS version to download from Windows.