# How can I use Windows to create an OS X Yosemite USB flash drive installer from the disk image (.dmg) file downloaded from Apple?

Tags: macos, windows, usb, install, dmg

### This question is **NOT** a duplicate of the question [How can I use Windows to create an OS X El Capitan or macOS Sierra USB flash drive installer from the disk image (.dmg) file downloaded from Apple?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-or-macos-sierra-usb-flash-dri)

Here is why:

> The `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file for Yosemite, which can be downloaded from Apple, uses the Apple Partition Map (APM). The The `InstallMacOSX.dmg` files for both El Capitan and Sierra, which can also be downloaded from Apple, use the GUID Partion Table instead of an APM. The Paragon Partition Manager Community Edition 64bit does not recognize APM. **Therefore, instructions for creating an USB Flash drive installer for El Capitan and Sierra can not be used to create an USB Flash drive installer for Yosemite.** This is why I wrote both questions and both accepted answers!

---

There are many posts on the Internet where instructions are given for creating OS X USB installers by using the [TransMac](https://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm) and other such applications on a Windows machine. Many of these posts assume one is starting with a disk image (.dmg) file made from an existing OS X USB flash drive installer.

An `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file for [OS X Yosemite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite), can be downloaded from the Apple website [How to download macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683). While this file can be restored to a flash drive, the result is not a working OS X Yosemite USB installer.

> Note: [This answer for Mavricks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142169/how-do-i-create-a-mac-bootable-usb-drive-using-windows/448553#448553) and [this answer for El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-usb-flash-drive-installer-fro/448121#448121) do not work for Yosemite.

How can I use Windows to create an OS X Yosemite USB flash drive installer from the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file for OS X Yosemite, which can be downloaded from Apple?

Comment: Is this question different from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-or-macos-sierra-usb-flash-dri or could we close one as a dupe?

Comment: @nohillside: The questions your are referring to are about different version of OS X/macOS. The accepted answer the question you have linked to will not work for Yosemite. This has already been stated in the above question. Which one of the two question were we thinking of closing?

Comment: None if it isn't useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Note: Links to instructions for other versions of OS X/macOS can found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/460961#460961).

Using Windows to create an USB flash drive OS X Yosemite installer requires third party software beyond just TransMac. The steps below outline one possible method for creating an USB flash drive OS X Yosemite installer using Windows and other free third party tools.

> Note: Windows 11 Pro version 21H2 was used to test this answer.

1. Use Microsoft Edge (or some other web browser) to download the following installers to your Downloads folder. The file names are current as of September 22, 2022. If both 32 bit and 64 bit versions are available, the 64 bit version is given in the table.

   | Product | Use | Installer | Type |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | [Yosemite 10.10](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683#browser)<sup>†</sup> | Free for use on Mac computers | `InstallMacOSX.dmg` | Mac Disk Image |
   | [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) | Free | `7z2201-x64.exe` | Application |
   | [GPT fdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/) | Free | `gdisk-windows-1.0.9.zip` | Compressed (zipped) Folder |
   | [dd for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/download) | Free | `ddrelease64.exe` | Application |
   | [TransMac](https://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm) | 15 day free trial | `tmsetup.zip` | Compressed (zipped) Folder |
   | [Paragon Partition Manager Community Edition 64bit](https://www.paragon-software.com/free/pm-express/) | Free for personal and home use | `Paragon-1081-FRU_WinInstallDemo_x64_17.9.1_000.exe` | Application |

   <sup>†</sup><sub>If you get the message “InstallMacOSX.dmg can't be download securely”, then select “Keep”, as shown below.</sub>

   [image]
2. Install all downloads except [“Yosemite 10.10”](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp711?locale=en_US), [“dd for Windows”](http://www.chrysocome.net//dd) and [“GPT fdisk”](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/). If you wish, the installed downloads can be uninstalled from the Windows Control Panel after use. Copy the command [`sgdisk64.exe`](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/sgdisk.html) from the downloaded GPT fdisk zip file to your Downloads folder.
3. Use a 7-Zip File Manager application window to extract the `OS X Install ESD` folder, `3.hfs` file and the `InstallAssistant.icns` file from the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` Mac disk image file to your Downloads folder. From a File Explorer window, start by navigating to your Downloads folder. In this window, right click on the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` Mac disk image file, then select "7-Zip" > "Open archive". This should open a 7-Zip File Manager application window. In this window, right click on each file or folder in the order given in the table below, then select the corresponding action.

   | File or Folder | Action | Type | Comment |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | `Install OS X` | Open | Folder |  |
   | `InstallMacOSX.pkg` | Open Inside * | Package File |  |
   | `InstallMacOSX.pkg` | Open | Folder |  |
   | `InstallESD.dmg` | Open | Mac Disk Image File |  |
   | `OS X Install ESD` | Copy To… | Folder | See footnote ‡ |
   | `OS X Install ESD` | Open | Folder |  |
   | `BaseSystem.dmg` | Open Inside * | Mac Disk Image File |  |
   | `3.hfs` | Copy To… | HFS+ volume image | See footnote ‡ |
   | `3.hfs` | Open | HFS+ volume image |  |
   | `OS X Base System` | Open | Folder |  |
   | `Install OS X Yosemite.app` | Open | Folder |  |
   | `Contents` | Open | Folder |  |
   | `Resources` | Open | Folder |  |
   | `InstallAssistant.icns` | Copy To… | Apple Icon Image File | See footnote ‡ |

   <sup>‡</sup><sub>The destination should be your Downloads folder. If this Downloads folder exists on a volume that is not NTFS formatted, then read [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-usb-flash-drive-installer-fro/449664#449664) and apply the same to this answer.</sub>

   When finished, close the 7-Zip File Manager application window.
4. Insert a 8 GB or larger flash drive into an USB port. If prompted, you do not need to initialize the flash drive.
5. Internally, the `BaseSystem.dmg` Mac disk image file contains a drive that is using the Apple Partition Map (APM), which is not well supported in a Windows environment. This step creates a GUID Partition Map on the USB flash drive instead of copying the APM from the `BaseSystem.dmg` file. Once the partition is created on the USB flash drive, the HFS volume image stored in the `3.hfs` is copied to this partition.

   > Note: See below for an alternative to this step, which does not require using GPT fdisk.

   Open an "Administrator: Windows PowerShell" window. (In other words, right click on the "Windows PowerShell" icon, then choose "Run as administrator" or "More" > "Run as administrator".) In the "Administrator: Windows PowerShell" window, take the following actions.

   - Change the current directory to be the location of your Downloads folder. If your Downloads folder is in the default location, then you can use the command given below. Otherwise, make the appropriate substitution.

     ```
     cd -d $env:userprofile\downloads
     ```

     > Note: If necessary, the File Explorer can be used to determined the location of your Downloads folder. From the File Explorer, right click on your Downloads folder, then select Properties. When the popup titled "Downloads Properties" appears, select either the General or Location tab to view the location.
   - Enter the following to get a list of drives. Note, `diskpart` is an interactive command.

     ```
     diskpart
     list disk
     ```
   - From the values in the `Disk ###` and `Size` columns, determine the number assigned to the USB flash drive. Here the number is assumed to be `1`. The following creates an empty Master Boot Record (MBR) table the USB flash drive, then exits the `diskpart` command. If your number is different, then make the appropriate substitution. Note, the `clean` command should be entered twice, as shown below.

     ```
     select disk 1
     clean
     clean
     exit
     ```
   - The  following sets the `dn` variable to 1. If the number assigned to your USB flash drive is different, then make the appropriate substitution.

     ```
     $dn=1
     ```
   - The following commands creates a HFS type partition, which is the same size as the `3.hfs` file. The `ddrelease64` command zeros the first 5120 bytes of the partition. Note, the `sgdisk64` command will automatically convert the drive to use the GUID Partition Table (GPT) partition style.

     ```
     .\ddrelease64 if=/dev/zero count=10 seek=40 of=\\?\Device\Harddisk$dn\Partition0
     $ns=(get-item 3.hfs).length/512
     .\sgdisk64 -a 8 -n 1:40:+$ns -t 1:af00 -i 1 "${dn}:"
     ```
   - The following command copies the HFS volume image in the `3.hfs` file to the HFS partition on the USB flash drive.

     ```
     .\ddrelease64 if=3.hfs bs=1M of=\\?\Device\Harddisk$dn\Partition1 --progress
     ```
   - Close the "Administrator: Command Prompt" window.
6. Open the Paragon Partition Manager 17 CE application. Select to resize the partition with the Apple HFS volume on the USB flash drive to maximum size, as shown below. Next, select the "Change now" button. When finished, select the "Close" button.

   [image]

   Next, select to change the volume label on this Apple HFS volume from "OS X Base System" to "Install Yosemite", as shown below. Next, select the "Change now" button. When finished, select the "Close" button.

   [image]

   When finished, close the Paragon Partition Manager 17 CE application window.
7. Open the TransMac application with Administrator privileges. (In other words, right click on the TransMac icon, then choose "Run as administrator" or "More" >  "Run as administrator".) In the TranMac application window, take the following actions.

   - Select "Tools" > "Settings" from the pulldown menu. In the "General" tab of the "Settings" popup, select the same copy options as shown below.

     [image: TransMac General Settings]

     Select `OK` when finished.
   - Navigate to root folder on the USB flash drive volume labeled `Install Yosemite`, as shown below.

     [image: root folder]
   - In the listview pane, right click, then select "Copy Here", as shown below.

     [image: root Copy Here]

     Select to copy the `OS X Install ESD\BaseSystem.chunklist` and `OS X Install ESD\BaseSystem.dmg` files in your Downloads folder. Repeat to copy the `InstallAssistant.icns` file in your Downloads folder.
   - In the listview pane, right click on the `InstallAssistant.icns` file, then select "Rename". Change the name to `.VolumeIcon.icns`. When finished, the treeview and listview panes should appear as shown below.

     [image]
   - Navigate to `System/Installation` folder on the USB flash drive volume labeled `Install Yosemite`, as shown below.

     [image: System/Installation folder]
   - In the listview pane, right click on the `Packages` file, then select "Delete". When prompted, select the `Yes` button in the popup to confirm.
   - In the listview pane, right click, then select "Copy Here", as shown below.

     [image: System/Installation Copy Here]

     Select to copy the `OS X Install ESD\Packages` folder in your Downloads folder. (This may take a while to complete.) When finished, the treeview and listview panes should appear as shown below.

     [image]
   - Close the TransMac window.
8. Use the File Explorer to delete the `OS X Install ESD` folder, `3.hfs` file and `InstallAssistant.icns` file in your Downloads folder. If you wish, you can also delete the downloaded files. When finished, close the File Explorer window, then empty the Recycle Bin.

### Alternate Step 5

This alternate step uses PowerShell and was tested using version 5.1.22000.832. If your version of PowerShell is compatible with this alternate step, then you can use this step.

Start by opening an "Administrator: Windows PowerShell" window. (In other words, right click on the "Windows PowerShell" icon, then choose "Run as administrator" or "More" > "Run as administrator".) In the "Administrator: Windows PowerShell" window, take the following actions.

- Change the current directory to be the location of your Downloads folder. If your Downloads folder is in the default location, then you can use the command given below. Otherwise, make the appropriate substitution.

  ```
  cd -d $env:userprofile\downloads
  ```

  > Note: If necessary, the File Explorer can be used to determined the location of your Downloads folder. From the File Explorer, right click on your Downloads folder, then select Properties. When the popup titled "Downloads Properties" appears, select either the General or Location tab to view the location.
- Enter the following to get a list of drives.

  ```
  get-disk
  ```
- From the values in the `Number` and `Total Size` columns, determine the number assigned to the USB flash drive. Here the number is assumed to be `1`. The  following sets the `dn` variable to 1. If your number is different, then make the appropriate substitution.

  ```
  $dn=1
  ```
- The following insures the USB drive does not have a partition style. If prompted, enter `y`.

  ```
  $do=get-disk -number $dn
  if ($do.partitionstyle -ne "raw") {clear-disk -number $dn -removedata -removeoem}
  ```
- The following creates a GUID Partition Table (GPT) on the USB flash drive. If a Microsoft Reserve partition is created, then this partition is removed. If prompted, enter `y`.

  ```
  initialize-disk -number $dn -partitionstyle gpt
  $do=get-disk -number $dn
  if ($do.numberofpartitions -ne 0) {remove-partition -disknumber $dn -partitionnumber 1}
  ```
- The following creates a HFS type partition, which is the same size as the `3.hfs` file.

  ```
  $ps=(get-item 3.hfs).length
  new-partition -disknumber $dn -Size $ps -gpttype "{48465300-0000-11aa-aa11-00306543ecac}" -alignment 4096
  ```
- The following command copies the HFS volume image in the `3.hfs` file to the HFS partition on the USB flash drive.

  ```
  .\ddrelease64 if=3.hfs bs=1M of=\\?\Device\Harddisk$dn\Partition1 --progress
  ```
- Close the "Administrator: Windows PowerShell" window.

### References

- [sgdisk](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/sgdisk.html)
- Other references given in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-can-i-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-usb-flash-drive-installer-fro/448121#448121).

Comment: What an ordeal, but thank you for writing this up!